# build and deploy from one dockerfile or have different files for each purpose?

Tags: dockerfile

I am creating react app and want to build and deploy the build to new container?

I am trying stages in dockerfile.

```
FROM node:alpine as builder

WORKDIR /app/

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine

EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: So what is your problem exactly?

Comment: Your 2nd phase doesn't copy the built application into the new, final container.

Comment: @StefanBecker thank you for your insites!helped me alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well the steps you followed is all correct,You just missed the part from where to copy the build folder and paste it in the nginx image.
by default nginx takes files to serve from

> usr/share/nginx/html

try the bellow code.

```
FROM node:alpine as builder

WORKDIR /app/

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine

EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

if it doesnt work do comment.